# No parameters are displayed in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on an ASP.NET Core Web API using EF. For some reason, one of my controllers doesn't display parameters from the object class.

User class:

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Cart Cart { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<Order> ListOfOrders { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

User controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AddUser")]
    public IActionResult AddUser(User u = null)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _userManager.CreateUser(u);

        return Ok();
    }
```

[image]

I don't really understand why there are no parameters in the Web API. I have another controller, which is set in the same way and the parameters are visible. Any help would be really appreciated here

Comment: You shouldn't be using EF entities as Web API DTOs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [article](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/), you could find the parameters is used for query parameter, header parameter or else.

Since this api method, you don't have any parameter(query string or else, the user is a complex type, it will be sent inside the request body), you will see the generated page say the parameter is null.

If you want to see the parameter, you could try to set a query string like below and you will see the parameter is not null.

Example like below:

```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("AddUser")]
   public IActionResult AddUser(User u , [FromQuery]string test)
   {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           return BadRequest(ModelState);
       }

      // _userManager.CreateUser(u);

       return Ok();
   }
```

Swagger page:

[image]